# Почему не работают переводы лейблов в форме YII2?

Tags: yii2

- Есть приложение, собранное на последней версии Yii2 из advanced
  сборки.
- Админка, в ней есть формы CRUD на несколько сущностей.
- В админ панели все формы работают с нормальным переводом.
- Эти же формы работают на публичной части сайта, и так же с переводом.
- Файл `frontend\messages\ru\app.php` присутствует, все константы в нем
  имеются и работают во всех формах которые были сделаны Gii.
- А в двух стандартных формах, которые идут в комплекте, Вход и
  Регистрация, перевод не работает.
- Сообщения об ошибках для этих полей, выводятся на русском, а сами
  лейблы как были на английском, так и остаются.
- В конфиге фронтенда все прописано, и 3 формы переводятся, а 2 нет.

В модели `common\models\User.php` имеется метод.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'username' => Yii::t('app', 'Login'),
        'phone' => Yii::t('app', 'Phone'),
        'religion' => Yii::t('app', 'Religion'),
        'password' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'),
    ];
}
```

Куда смотреть, сбился уже с толку?

Comment: А разве лейбы не задаются отдельно в модели?

Comment: Они заданы, в бек, все работает как надо а в паблик нет.

Comment: Нужен код форм, которые работают и которые не работают. Можно еще файлы переводов добавить в вопрос.

Comment: @fedornabilkin что за глупость, коды форм могут быть абсолютно одинаковыми... дело в модели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все банально и просто.

Как я указывал выше, что метод `attributeLabels` находился в `common\models\User.php` а модели форм не наследуют его, они наследуют `Moldel`, следовательно данный метод надо было добавить в `common\models\LoginForm.php` и `frontend\models\SignupForm.php`